# Get Facebook profile pics via Codeigniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I want to get profile pics, friend list from my facebook id  and as I'm new I would prefer step by step explanation

Comment: Hi Tushar and welcome to SO. Please take your time to read this article: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Step1 - Get the users Facebook ID - **DONE**
- Step2 - Make a call to this URL - `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_FBID/picture`
- Step3 - You're done :)

Usually I'll simply place that url within an `<img>` tag -

`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture" width="100">`

Live demo ([check the source of this post for proof](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d788ee5e-fd5d-4140-8fdd-2399ff1a611e/view-source) ;) -

[image]

*Yes, Mark Zuckerberg's Facebook ID is `4`*

Comment: thanx.....but how can i get all the list of my friends with their facebook profile pics.

Comment: Oh - I missed that part.  To get a users friend list you'll have to authenticate your user and request the basic information on that user which will include their friends... I don't have much knowledge about codeigniter and Facebook integration but here is what looks like a good place to start - http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/